# Java TCP sockets, sending and receiving objects in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, multiplayer

I'm a a beginner programmer, currently stuck on a java project. I have a fully working singleplayer minesweeper game, object-oriented, and I'm trying to implement a TCP multiplayer function. The game has a control class, which handles the view, game field, timer, labels, has the action listeners, etc.
For multiplayer, I'm trying to make a separate thread, which has the Socker and the ServerSocket, and depending on the parameters passed on by the constructor, acts as a host or client. While running, it should be trying to read my custom Packet class from the input stream, and another method can send packets. Here is the code:

public class MultiThread extends Thread {

```
GameControl gc;
ServerSocket servSocket;
Socket socket;
Packet data;
ObjectInputStream incoming;
ObjectOutputStream outgoing;
Boolean isHost;
Boolean commEnd;

public MultiThread(GameControl gc, Boolean isHost) {
    this.gc = gc;
    this.isHost = isHost;
    this.commEnd = false;
    gc.chatDialog.setVisible(true);
}

public void run() {
    try {
        if (isHost) {
            servSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
            gc.chatDialog.status.setText("Awaiting connection...");
            socket = servSocket.accept();
            gc.chatDialog.status.setText("Connected.");
            incoming = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            outgoing = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        else if (!isHost){
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                gc.chatDialog.status.setText("Connected.");
                incoming = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                outgoing = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            }
            else {
                gc.chatDialog.status.setText("No connection.");
            }
        }


        while (!commEnd) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                data = (Packet)incoming.readObject();
                System.out.println(data.msg);
                gc.chatDialog.chatArea.append(data.getMsg());   
            }
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        System.out.println("asd");
        gc.chatDialog.status.setText("No connection");
        incoming.close();
        outgoing.close();
        socket.close();
        servSocket.close();
    }

        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void sendPacket(Packet p) {
    try {
        outgoing.writeObject(p);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

}

The connection gets established on localhost, but I'm getting an exception thrown when trying to initialize the incoming and outgoing fields.
Sorry if the code is a mess, I get the feeling I'm in some serious misunderstanding, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the exception stack trace as well for the best possible answer.

Comment: Allright, it seems like I'm only getting a NullPointerException thrown when trying to invoke the sendPacket method. However the code below "incoming = new ObjectInputStream(...)" is never reached, comfirmed by println-s, but I don't get any exceptions right away, is that possible?

Comment: OK, my bad, I wasn't sure how to describe the problem, but I managed to solve it by getting the OutputStream first and flushing it, but trying to find the exception made me realize the constructor is blocking, so thanks. :)